# How to use the set of user_ids in a table and get the username of the users with those ids from the User table

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySQL and already kinda struggling to query something that I want.

There is a table called Subject that looks like

```
+---------+----------+-------------+------------+------------+--+
| user_id | subject  | description | created_at | updated_at |  |
+---------+----------+-------------+------------+------------+--+
|       1 | A        | non         | 3434343434 |   34343433 |  |
|       2 | B        | non         | 3434343434 | 3434343434 |  |
|       3 | C        | non         | 3434343434 | 3434343434 |  |
|       3 | D        | non         | 3434343434 | 3434343434 |  |
+---------+----------+-------------+------------+------------+--+
```

and a table User that only has columns `user_id` and `username`

I want to get the set of usernames that exists in the Subject table.

`SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM Subject` gives me a set of `user_id`s.
How can I use these `user_id`s and get their `usernames` from the User table?

Thanks!

Comment: Use an `IN` clause or an `EXISTS` clause. ( `IN` is easier to write and read in my opinion. I'd use `EXISTS` or more complicated things where `IN` doesn't suffice.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a fairly verbatim translation of your requirements, we could use exists logic here:

```sql
SELECT u.username
FROM User u
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Subject s WHERE s.user_id = u.user_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using `inner join`

```
select distinct u.username from User u inner join Subject s on s.user_id=u.user_id
```

Comment: A bad suggestion in my opinion. Why join all rows only to dismiss most of them later? You are building a large intermediate result you don't really need. If you want to join, join the distinct values instead, i.e. join with a subquery (derived table). But for the given problem, `IN` and `EXISTS` are much more appropriate, because they exist exactly for this type of tasks.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner thanks for your comment and I learn from it!